How to support these bookshelves that are over an on open space?
I have built many "built-in" bookcases in our home: plywood carcasses with a top and bottom shelf dadoed in, a shelf pins for the rest of the shelves and a 1/2" plywood back, screwed to wall after being leveled and shimmed. No problem. Basically this very system: New Yankee Workshop library system.
I now want to build a similar thing in our living room but with a twist: 2 bookcases on either end of a sofa but with additional shelves built like a bridge above the sofa across the 2 end units.  Here are some pictures that help visualize it:


My questions are:

How are these supported? By the twin bookcases and then the plywood backs screwed to wall?
How long of a span can I get away with for a shelf 12" deep? I usually make the shelves out of 3/4" ply with a 2" hardwood front piece to stiffen it and hide the plies. These probably need to be thicker than 3/4"?

Any other suggestions?
Cheers

I would build these like upper kitchen cabinets - supported entirely by attaching to the studs in the wall. Yes, they will also connect to the bookcases on the ends, which will provide additional strength and stability.
1/2" plywood by itself may not be enough, because books can get quite heavy, but if you have additional plywood strips or dimensional lumber behind the plywood back (so it isn't obvious) and screwed into the studs, it should work very well.

Both of the pictured examples have face frames, which will provide enhanced support from deflection.  The important point here is that the horizontal members (particularly the top) need to be properly secured to the wall structure.

The 3/4" plywood base is plenty thick enough for carrying the weight of a reasonable amount of books.  Making it stiffer is easily done with the 2" hardwood you use to cover the front.
Dado the 2" trim piece about 1/2" deep and glue and screw ( with finishing screws) to the plywood. Also glue and nail the base plywood to the back. Attaching the back to the back side of the shelf. Once assembled, the unit will be plenty strong.
When assembled with the back and dividers, this box will be able to be installed as a span and there should be no measurable deflection from books.
Assuming a normal sofa may be 7 feet long, you can do this to a full 8 foot piece of 3/4 plywood and have your span. It could be made longer as well using the same method then adding a 1/2 lap about 4 inches to connect the pieces of plywood. This will not be as strong as a single piece, but will be able to carry reasonable weight over the longer span.  Of course attach the back to studs in the wall as you would normally do.
Of course use common sense and arrange items properly. You may not want to display your collection of granite chunks and bowling balls on that shelf.
